# Facebook authentication from restricted zone

Tags: facebook, authentication

Consider the following situation: internet provider has a selfcare site that is integrated with facebook, i.e. user can login toselfcare site using his facebook credentials.

However, when user has not paid for the internet access, he is limited to the provider's only sites (ex. selfcare.provider.com). In this case, facebook integration stops working due to access restrictions.

Question is: is there a way of restricting access to facebook in such a way, so that only login can be enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to allow users to authenticate against your app without allowing them to access Facebook itself?

I don't think that will be possible short of applying some custom logic on your end to try to determine if a request to Facebook is for login purposes or to access Facebook itself - there's no API for this.

Comment: yes, this is exacly what I want to do, and, I think some tricky logic on the client side will be required too, unfortunately